# I can't connect to MySQL Server Instance 4.1 using Workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql, workbench

in Workbench 6.3 I can connect and see tables in version 5.6 on my dev computer. I can even connect and see tables across internet for version 4.3.3 that is our production database.

But I installed MySQL 4.1 (trying to be as close to 4.3.3) on dev computer and Workbench sees it and I can open it, but I can't create a connection inside in order to import data or do anything. When installing the 4.1 server I chose 3307 since 5.6 was on 3306. I changed it to 3306 for 4.1, and I stopped 5.6 version in Services.

MySQL41 service is started (Windows 7).

In information window on left it says: 
Name: Local instance MySQL41
Host: local host
Port:3306 
NO CONNECTION (in red)

It finds the instance in main window of Workbench when I click on "Rescan for local instances".  Here is the connection string behind what it finds with the scan: root@localhost:3306

It also will open the server if I click on connection it makes. But it doesn't let me make a connection inside the server.

If I try to start the server from inside Workbench I get the following:

2015-05-20 11:20:13 - Starting server...
2015-05-20 11:20:18 - Server start done.
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Checking server status...
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Assuming server is not running
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Checking server status...
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2015-05-20 11:20:19 - Assuming server is not running

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. I had a previous mySQL server installation (with non-standard port), and I re-installed to a different directory & port. Then I got the same issue. To resolve, you click on home + add new connection.

If you need to know the port of your server, you can find it when you start My SQL command line client via All Programs -> MySQL ->  MySQL ServerX.Y  -> MySQL X.Y Command Line Client and run command status (as below)

[image: how to create]

[image: how to find port]